# How to add box shadow only to right side

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a theme in WordPress, In that, I need to add box-shadow only to the right side. I referred to some styles but it won't work. I want exactly that shown in the screenshot link below
https://prnt.sc/vxhfjo. Can anyone help me to implement this in my theme?

Comment: Do you mean the transparent to white gradient over the top of the box? I would suspect that is a psudeo element with something like `background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);`

Answer (score 0):

Box-Shadow CSS Generator => https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/